# MySQL: SELECT DISTINCT REGEX value

Tags: mysql, regex, select, distinct

In my MySQL database I have a row column called `test_column` with the following rows:

```
dtq test dis
ged something fbd
edf something tds
zhs nothing edk
dda anything zhg
hvf nothing ert
asf nothing vbg
```

I'm looking for the string between the first three and the last three characters. I can get these values with REGEX like this:

```
^\w{3}\s(\w+)\s\w{3}$
```

I want to SELECT DISTINCT these values.

Expected output is the following:

```
test
something
nothing
anything
```

How can I do that with a MySQL command?

Comment: please first post what you tried

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

Comment: `\b` is available in MySQL 8, not mysql 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `regexp_replace()` as follows:

```
select distinct regexp_replace(col, '(^\\w{3}\\s)|(\\s\\w{3}$)', '') new_col from mytable
```

This works by replacing the first and last words (and the following/preceding spaces) with the empty string. The first and last words must be 3 characters long.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=166063b114a6cf7cfd89225d2ccbfab9)**:

```
| new_col   |
| :-------- |
| test      |
| something |
| nothing   |
| anything  |
```

You can make the regex a little more generic so it accepts also starting and ending words that have a length other than 3 characters and sequences of more than one space:

```
regexp_replace(col, '(^\\w+\\s+)|(\\s+\\w{+$)', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need a regexp if this suffices

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', 2)
```

However, this assumes your "3 characters" or `\w{3}` (which is really 3 alphanumeric characters) is not really the test, but instead the space is critical.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex if that is all you want (remove first 4 and last 4 characters):

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(test_column,5,LENGTH(test_column)-8)
FROM mytable
```

[Demo on dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=17c3dba6d54261b497a4e49bb642dfb9)

or everything after the first space, up until the second space:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(test_column,' ',2),' ',-1)
FROM mytable
```

[Demo on dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=de106fd462eca01e887590ce043e4ea1)